# Parsing times with non-local zone abbreviations in Ruby: offset is correct but zone name is lost

Tags: ruby

Ruby's Time only seems to "remember" my local zone name and UTC. The time object that is created has the correct offset, but #zone is nil. This is easy to see in the console (I am on MDT):

```
>> Time.parse("12:00 AM MDT")
=> 2018-03-14 00:00:00 -0600
>> Time.parse("12:00 AM MDT").zone
=> "MDT"

>> Time.parse("12:00 AM PST")
=> 2018-03-14 00:00:00 -0800
>> Time.parse("12:00 AM PST").zone
=> nil

>> Time.parse("12:00 AM EDT")
=> 2018-03-14 00:00:00 -0400
>> Time.parse("12:00 AM EDT").zone
=> nil
```

UTC also works, but that seems to be about it.

Is there a way to preserve the abbreviation for other time zones?

Answer (score 0):

You can not get `zone` name from Time object, instead you can get the `offset` value from it. There is no support for [timezone abbreviations in ruby](https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo/issues/38)

```
time = Time.parse("12:00 AM PST")
time.gmt_offset
```

Please note that `Time.zone` is a feature of [Rails' ActiveSupport](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html) - it is not provided by TZInfo. ActiveSupport uses TZInfo internally to implement support for time zones.

You can pass zone name to ActiveSupport to construct new time with zone name information.

```
time = ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Hawaii'].parse('12 AM')
time.zone # 'HST'
```

You can also use `in_time_zone` method in rails.

```
time = Time.parse('12 AM').in_time_zone('Hawaii')
time.zone # 'HST'
```

Hope it helps !